# CSS - Long text bumps down content

Tags: html, css, overflow, word-wrap

I'm using nested `div` elements styled to be like a table with rows and cells. In each one, there will be a checkbox, an image, and some text content. If the text content is longer than the image is wide, then the div containing the image and content is bumped such that it is no longer inline with the checkbox.

I'd like the text to wrap before that happens instead.

The content is actually dynamic (using ASP.NET), so I cannot fix the width of the containers or use JavaScript.

[image]

I created a JSFiddle that replicates the problem I'm having:

https://jsfiddle.net/L1h0y7yn/

```css
.table {
    display: table;
    width: 800px;
    height: 100%;
    table-layout: fixed;
}

.row {
    display: table-row;
}

.cell {
    display: table-cell;
    padding-top: 24px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    overflow: hidden;
}

input {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.right {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.image {
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    background-color: darkcyan;
}

.content {
 
}
```

```html
<div id="table" class="table">
    <div id="row_1" class="row">
        <div id="cell_1" class="cell">
            <input type="checkbox" />
            <div class="right">
                <div class="image"></div>
                <div class="content">
                    This is some text
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="cell_2" class="cell">
            <input type="checkbox" />
            <div class="right">
                <div class="image"></div>
                <div class="content">
                    This is some text
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="cell_3" class="cell">
            <input type="checkbox" />
            <div class="right">
                <div class="image"></div>
                <div class="content">
                    This is some text
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="cell_4" class="cell">
            <input type="checkbox" />
            <div class="right">
                <div class="image"></div>
                <div class="content">
                    This is some longer block of text content.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're decided on a width of `120px` on your image then you can set your content to the same to "wrap it" within the table-cell.

```
.content {
    width: 120px;
}
```

```css
.table {
    display: table;
    width: 800px;
    height: 100%;
    table-layout: fixed;
}

.row {
    display: table-row;
}

.cell {
    display: table-cell;
    padding-top: 24px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    overflow: hidden;
}

input {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.right {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.image {
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    background-color: darkcyan;
}

.content {
 width: 120px;
}
```

```html
<div id="table" class="table">
    <div id="row_1" class="row">
        <div id="cell_1" class="cell">
            <input type="checkbox" />
            <div class="right">
                <div class="image"></div>
                <div class="content">
                    This is some text
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="cell_2" class="cell">
            <input type="checkbox" />
            <div class="right">
                <div class="image"></div>
                <div class="content">
                    This is some text
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="cell_3" class="cell">
            <input type="checkbox" />
            <div class="right">
                <div class="image"></div>
                <div class="content">
                    This is some text
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="cell_4" class="cell">
            <input type="checkbox" />
            <div class="right">
                <div class="image"></div>
                <div class="content">
                    This is some longer block of text content.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I believe  OP would like a flexible width container

Comment: I was able to figure it out by combining this answer with Derek's answer. Since the image was indeed set to a fixed width, I'm okay with setting the content's width. I'll just put a comment in my code that both should be changed if one is. Thanks.

Comment: Actually, scrapping the `flex` part from Derek's answer. Flex doesn't work in IE very well.

Answer (score 0):

I updated your fiddle.  I changed your .row and .cell to flexbox containers

https://jsfiddle.net/L1h0y7yn/1/

```
.row {
  display: flex;
}

.cell {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  padding-top: 24px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: This did partially work, but in Chrome it made the checkbox tiny for some reason (not in the JSFiddle, though.)